# Excel: If function that filters a table by two columns and sees if a third column has more than one unique value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to identify if a customer (customer A) purchased both Apples and Bananas on the same day based on a table of data. Column A identifies the Customer, Column B the day that the customer made a purchase, and Column C the fruit that they purchased. I simply want an IF statement that indicates whether, if on any day, the specified customer purchased both Apples and Bananas. In other words, for a specified customer, I want an output cell to indicate if "Yes", there is a day on which the specified customer purchased apples and bananas, or "No" there wasn't.

```
Customer Date           Fruit Purchased
A        2016/09/08     Apples
B        2016/09/09     Apples
C        2016/08/10     Apples
A        2016/09/08     Bananas
B        2016/08/12     Bananas
C        2016/09/13     Bananas
A        2016/09/13     Apples
```

Given the above table, if I specify Customer A as my customer, the formula should indicate "Yes", as customer A purchased Apples and Bananas on 2016/09/08.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in column D:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2,C:C,"Bananas")+COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2,C:C,"Apples")>=2,"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an "array formula" is probably the easiest way to do it:

Enter the following an instead of just pressing enter, use Control + Shift + Enter.  If you don't use Control + Shift + Enter it'll just come up with "NO" for every row.

```
=IF(SUM(IF(A$2:A$8=A2,IF(B$2:B$8=B2,IF(C$2:C$8=C2,1,1),0),0))>1,"YES","NO")
```